# can't access images in assets folder (ruby-on-rails)

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to access images in the /assets/images directory in my scss file like:

```
background-image: url(/assests/traffic_lights_red.png);
```

nothing is returned 
When i hit the URL directly using `http://localhost:3000/assests/traffic_lights_red.png` I get a routing error: `No route matches [GET] "/assests/traffic_lights_red.png"`

I've read some of the other postings on this topic and it looks like this should work, why would I get the routing error?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well this might be a dumb answer, since its probably a typo, but

```
background-image: url(/assests/traffic_lights_red.png);
```

should be

```
background-image: url(/assets/traffic_lights_red.png);
```

Comment: right on! i'm always blind to my own typos. :) thanks!

Comment: Hah :) really expected that typo to only be a typo in the question. But I know how you feel.. so often we make typos that others spot in a second while you just dont see it.